# How to handle Integer.MAX_VALUE in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, dataset, random-forest

I would like to know to know why random forest classification doesn't support large number of observations in Spark. If I give more than 7500 I am get

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example. Why the reason  why your code fails is clear possible solutions differ depending on a context.

Comment: you want me to provide the dataset which have used or what?

Comment: No, but code is useful. See the reason for closing.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to limitation of Spark. The underlying abstraction for blocks in spark is a ByteBuffer  which would limit the size of the block to 2GB.
This has implication not just for managed blocks in use, but also for shuffle blocks. This is an issue with spark when using on non trivial datasets.

Comment: whether there is any solution for this

Comment: Not at this point of time.